# Dismiss Popover with a Button Done or Cancel on the Popover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I have created 2 ViewControllers, one is called `ViewController` and the other one `catViewController` with it's own class.
 In the ViewController when I press "`Category`" button in the `barbutton`, I call the catViewController with a Popover style with the arrow pointing on the Category button.

The `catViewController` contains a collection view and cells. If I press outside the popover or on the button "Category" It will dismiss the popover no problem. But I am trying to dismiss it with a done or cancel button directly on a barbutton within the popover, It will not dismiss.

I am using `[self.catPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];` It is allocated and instinsiated in the ViewController using the storyboard identifier and I am trying to dismiss it in catViewController.

**How do I pass or use the reference pointer of ViewController** from or to catViewController so that I can have control of it.

Answer (score 3):

Create a property in popover content view controller. Like this

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UIPopoverController *popOverController;
```

And assign this property when you are showing popover

```
ViewController2 *objContentViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc] init];
popOver = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:objContentViewController];
objContentViewController.popOverController = popOver;
```

And then call below statement from your bar button click method...

```
[self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:TRUE];
```

Comment: I would suggest using a `weak` property to avoid circular references.